# Typescript overloding

Tags: typescript, oop, overloading

Guys  where is an error in this code,
I suppose, I am covering all possible situations,
compiler saying I am wrong here - function position(a: number): IPositionDefault ,
but if there is one argument I returning object that looks like IPositionDefault, no?

```
function position(): IPosition
function position(a: number): IPositionDefault 
function position(a: number, b: number) :IPosition
function position(a?: number, b? :number){
    if (!a && !b){
        return {x: undefined, y: undefined}
    }
    if (a && !b){ 
        return {x: a, y: undefined, default: a.toString()}
    }
    if (!a && b){
        return {x: b, y: undefined, default: b.toString()}
    }
    
    return {x: a, y: b}
}
```

I expected to see no error in compiler

Comment: What? It's not clear what the error is. Please [edit] your question to include the exact compiler message. Also the compiler should tell you *where* the error is, so why are you asking us?

Comment: In order for us to reproduce the problem, you'll need to share the definition of the `IPosition` and `IPositionDefault` types

Comment: Notice that `!x` also holds if `x` is `0`. You'll want `x != null` or `typeof x != 'undefined'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need for error to go away to do is to define a return type of your actual function implementation.

Change:

```
function position(a?: number, b? :number){
```

To:

```
function position(a?: number, b? :number): IPosition | IPositionDefault {
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2BnYZiYjIDeAUMhcgB4BcyIArgLYBG0yAPsgyACYQxQEXgG5ylAJ51Grdlx79BIYWIC%20pUqEixEKDDjwEQAEQFwGAGzDIIVSH2xosufIRLiKi81brYwUUABzNQ0YHgRXIgAHA0iACgBKOn0XI1IwkAijZBjUwji4aWY2KCSnWKNTeEtrdPDInIr8wvpi6AAaZBYi2VLkGhTDQjrMhtyhkAKAfh6SzpYp-pkSssGGrjXKsxr3SmRgGGQ4gEI4ZAAyc%20RjlgSyPb2oCDAGKCJiWm4%20ASFeTqkvopfuo9iDKAcjmdLtdbsRkB4Hk8Xm8SJ84P86Aofso-sgvDU6HAAHRgTAAZX8QUSYIoNP2hxOUKusIRj2er3enxYGMB2OEnXxPi6JPJlJAgWpCPUCKRHNRhJ5LHUqiAA).

Comment: Exactly! But if there is only one type, of what function returns, we don't should to declare it?

Comment: @Eugene Correct

Comment: last question please, is it specific of language, or some OOP logic inside it?

Comment: @Eugene Specific to TypeScript

Comment: Got it, many thanks, have a good one!

Comment: @VladHolubiev this pattern doest maintain well, you cant keep adding more interfaces to the or condition, probable should sperate the common methods and properties of both interface into a third interface and then implement the 3rd interface.